# printing barcode from winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, barcode

I want to print barcodes in a winforms application with the normal printing facilities, not through a ZPL like language. I can print anything just not a regular barcode

```
using (PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument())
{
    pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Printer";
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintLabel);
    pd.Print();
}

private void pdPrintLabel(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    Graphics g = ev.Graphics;

    using (Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 6))
    {
       g.DrawString(????????? what to do for barcode????);
    }
}
```

Comment: how does your `barcode data` look like? (its representation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We were using [Barcode Rendering Framework](https://barcoderender.codeplex.com/):

```
BarcodeDraw bdraw = BarcodeDrawFactory.GetSymbology(BarcodeSymbology.Code128);
Image barcodeImage = bdraw.Draw("barcodetext", barcodeImageHeight);
g.DrawImage(barcodeImage, barcodeRect);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void printDoc()
{

    PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
    BarcodeDraw bdraw = BarcodeDrawFactory.GetSymbology(BarcodeSymbology.Code128);
    Image barcodeImage = bdraw.Draw("PO7120172733039800", 50);

    document.PrintPage += delegate(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(barcodeImage, 0, 0);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("PO7120172733039800", new Font("arial", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Black),0,50);
    };
    document.Print();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Infragistics UltraCode128Barcode1 barcode and it worked for me

```
  Private Sub btnprintbarcodes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnprintbarcodes.Click

        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End Sub

   Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        e.PageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = ApplicationHelper.GetApplicationSettingValue("Barcode_Printer_Name")
        Dim barcodeImageFile As String = String.Empty
        If UltraCode128Barcode1.Data IsNot Nothing Then
            barcodeImageFile = String.Concat(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid(), ".tiff")
            UltraCode128Barcode1.SaveTo(barcodeImageFile, ImageFormat.Tiff)
            Dim barcodeimage = Image.FromFile(barcodeImageFile)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(barcodeimage, 0, 0)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(UltraCode128Barcode1.Data, New Font("arial", 8), New SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 50)
        End If
        If (File.Exists(barcodeImageFile)) Then
            'File.Delete(barcodeImageFile)
        End If
    End Sub

  Private Sub PrintDocument1_BeginPrint(sender As Object, e As PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.BeginPrint
        ApplicationHelper.ShowGeneralDialog("The Program is about to print barcode(s).Make sure your barcode printer is on and loaded")
    End Sub
```